# connect ECONNREFUSED 43.205.72.30:27017 while connecting to Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, backend, mern

My MERN app is trying to connect with the Atlas service to read and write some data.

Multiple times while firing up the backend server, I get this error: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 43.205.72.30:27017`

When I successfully connect, I work fine for a while, but it again throws an error.. There is a complete response I get:

```
{
    "message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 43.205.72.30:27017",
    "stack": "MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 43.205.72.30:27017\n    at connectionFailureError (D:\\Projects\\MERN\\munch-lane\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\cmap\\connect.js:379:20)\n    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\\Projects\\MERN\\munch-lane\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\cmap\\connect.js:285:22)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)\n    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)\n    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)"
}
```

Initially, I was working on my WiFi, but other articles on the internet stated the same issues with WiFi, maybe due to port 27017 not being open on the router. So, I tried using my mobile hotspot, and it started working fine for a while before again throwing the same issues.

I have added 0.0.0.0 to the whitelist IPs. NodeJs version is `v20.10.0`

The connection string is: `mongodb+srv://techmirtz:<password>@cluster0.yqhzzuj.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0`

I see many similar questions addressed but most of them are for localhost one, not Atlas.

Comment: Is it always that same IP address?